# Prob question on dice rolling and expected value

Tags: probability, dice

So let's say I roll 3 dice.

- If they show all the same number, I will EARN 10£
- If all numbers are different, I will LOSE 2£
- If they show two numbers equal and one different, I will EARN 5£

What would be my expected return per roll?

If we calculate the probabilities (if I am not wrong)

- 6/216 --> earn 10£
- 90/216 --> earn 5£
- 120/216 --> lose 2£

How would I proceed to calculate the expected value per roll?

**EDIT**

Would the EV be: (6/216)x10 + (90/216)x5 - (120/216)x2 = **1.25**?

Comment: Probability that all numbers are different $ = \frac{6 \times 5 \times 4}{6 \times 6 \times 6} = \frac{120}{216}$. Probability that two are equal and one different is the remaining probability, that is, $ = 1 - \frac{120}{216} - \frac{6}{216} = \frac{90}{216}$.

Comment: Thank you!! how would I calculate the expected value per roll?

Comment: I have edited the Q with my guess, is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

By definition for discrete random variable, the expected value is the sum of the product of possible values of the random variable with it's probability. Say, X can be $10$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, X can be $\left(-100\right)$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, and X can be $0$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. Then the expected value is $10 \cdot\frac{1}{2} + \left(-100\right)\cdot\frac{1}{4} + 0\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \left(-20\right)$

So, the expected value is $10 \cdot\frac{6}{216} + 5\cdot\frac{90}{216} + \left(-2\right)\cdot\frac{120}{216} = \frac{270}{216}$